# Changing Remote Control Mapping

Tags: remote-control

I just got my remote control working, but some of the buttons do things I don't like (e.g. the button with a Windows logo on it opens my default music player, the OK button doesn't do anything). How can I change which commands are mapped to which buttons and map specific commands to buttons that do not appear to have anything mapped to them?

Answer (score 0):

The program you use for remote controls is typically lirc (Linux Infrared Remote Control). Here is a link to some of their documentation on setting it up, http://www.lirc.org/html/configure.html It can be pretty involved, depending on what you want to do.